# INVALID_ACCESS_ERR while retrieving data from sqlite in Android using phonegap API

Tags: javascript, cordova, sqlite

This is my Javascript code

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Populate the database
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    alert("populateDB");
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
    alert("queryDB");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    alert("querySuccess");
    // this will be empty since no rows were inserted.
    console.log("Insert ID = " + results.insertId);
    // this will be 0 since it is a select statement
    console.log("Rows Affected = " + results.rowAffected);
    // the number of rows returned by the select statement
    console.log("Insert ID = " + results.rows.length);
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("errorCB");
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("successCB");
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("onDeviceReady");
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

But i am getting this error log

```
D/DroidGap(1674): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/DroidGap(1674): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html   baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
D/DroidGap(1674): DroidGap.init()
D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1674): Ignore this event
D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1674): Ignore this event
D/dalvikvm(1674): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1758 objects / 121720 bytes in 172ms
I/Database(1674): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source   line 25467
D/PhoneGapLog(1674): DroidGap:  onExceededDatabaseQuota estimatedSize: 200000    currentQuota: 0  totalUsedQuota: 0
D/PhoneGapLog(1674): calling quotaUpdater.updateQuota newQuota: 200000
D/PhoneGapLog(1674): INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: DOM Exception 15: A parameter or an operation  was not supported by the underlying object.
D/PhoneGapLog(1674): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 232 :  INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: DOM Exception 15: A parameter or an operation was not supported by the    underlying object.
E/Web Console(1674): INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: DOM Exception 15: A parameter or an operation was not supported by the underlying object. at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:232
D/PhoneGapLog(1674): Error processing SQL: 0
D/PhoneGapLog(1674): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 243 : Error processing SQL: 0
```

I am using Phonegap version 1.4.0.
Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Web SQL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#database-query-results):

> The insertId attribute must return the row ID of the row that the
>   SQLResultSet object's SQL statement inserted into the database, if the
>   statement inserted a row. If the statement inserted multiple rows, the
>   ID of the last row must be the one returned. **If the statement did not
>   insert a row, then the attribute must instead raise an
>   INVALID_ACCESS_ERR exception.**

Your `queryDB` method does a SELECT. So, by definition, it can't insert any rows. Therefore, `insertId` is not valid in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you already fixed this, but I was using your same example code, with the same problem.  The example was incorrect.   Phonegap now has an updated example.  Replace your query method with

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
console.log("Insert ID = " + results.insertId);
} catch(exc) {
// console.log(exc)
console.log("Insert ID = " + null);
}
```

Comment: describe why have you just entered this text,and how it will help user to solve his problem and do read FAQ before answering